# UK Standard visitor Visa bank statements

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I recently applied for a UK standard visa and am awaiting a decision. I have two bank accounts which I use interchangeably, so I submitted my salary slips which map to one of the accounts. All the cash deposits in my account were done by my family and most of them were used to buy personal items. My second account, which is my savings account, shows large withdrawals for the same. I also submitted my tax returns which show that the money was earned by me.

Will the cash deposits lead to a refusal, since I explained in my cover letter that the same amount was used to buy personal items?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question by mentioning your citizenship, as well as what do you mean by large amounts?

Comment: Also, please see the related questions on the right side and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: It depends on the frequency and amount of the cash deposits. You don’t need to be concerned about infrequent/small deposits. However you *do* need to explain frequent/large cash deposits, and also show where the person who deposited the cash got it from. Failing to explain *and document the source of* material cash deposits might well lead to a refusal.